# How to wrap blazor WebComponent in shadow dom

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, shadow-dom

I am using [BlazorCustomElements](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/BlazorCustomElements) to wrap my application in custom element. However it sill shares styles with host page.

Using just javascript, I'd do something like:

```
const header = document.createElement('header');
const shadowRoot = header.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello Shadow DOM</h1>'; // Could also use appendChild().
```

however the framework supplies all this code for me, so I cannot just do it this way.

How can I wrap my component in shadow dom, so styles are not shared?

Comment: TIL that there is such a thing as a shadow dom - I cant help you (Blazor wasm dev so i looked at the question) but thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [Blazor CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: @JesseGood I want to cut my component from existing app, not other way around. This also includes scripts

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is not good idea due to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46961